# mathbb unknown control sequence

Tags: amsmath, amsfonts

I'm new in Latex and I'm using MIKTeX. For writing equation in a template for a journal, I write the following:

```
\[S_{ij}=  \mathbb{G} \]
```

but I face this error:

> Undefined control sequence. [S_{ij}= \mathbb

How could I fix that?

note: I have installed "amsfonts" and "amsmath".

Comment: add `\usepackage{amsfonts}` it is not enough to install amsfonts you need to reference the package in the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, where in the code?

Comment: yes after `\documentclass` before `\begin{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Thanks a lot.